# How to iterate and print each element in list (Python)

Tags: python, list

`arr(['36 36 30','47 96 90','86 86 86']`

I want to store and print the values like this,

```
36
36 
30
47
...
```

How do I do this using python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the simplest way is to use `for` and `str.split()`

```
arr=['36 36 30','47 96 90','86 86 86']
for block in arr:
    cells = block.split()
    for cell in cells: 
        print(cell)
```

prints

```
36
36
30
47
96
90
86
86
86
```

you can also use a list comprehension like so, which returns the same result.

```
print("\n".join([ele for block in arr for ele in block.split()]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lists` and split in python. Try in this way:

```
arr = ['36 36 30','47 96 90','86 86 86']
for i in arr:
    elems = i.split()
    for elem in elems:
        print(elem)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try the following approach.  Build a single string of space separated numbers, split it, then join on newline.

```py
inp = ['36 36 30', '47 96 90', '86 86 86']
output = '\n'.join(' '.join(inp).split())
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
36
36
30
47
96
90
86
86
86
```